# Define a function head inside a conf file

Tags: python, dictionary, switch-statement, python-config

I am using a dictionary/get construct as a switch case in Python. It looks similar to this one:

```
def switch_function(pluginID, param):
switcher = {
    'someid': somefunction(param),
}
return switch_function.get(pluginID, None)
```

However, i want to to extend the dictionary by another key value pair, which is defined in a conf file. I want a function head as an value. The function head should be the head of that function, which should be executed in the switch case, for a specific pluginid.  The config file will look something like this:

```
[aSection]
pluginid='anotherid'
functionHead: anotherfunction2
```

Extending the dictionary should be easy, but is it possible to map a function head as an value inside a conf file?

Answer (score 1):

The following example will give you an `exec` clause. Your `dict` should extend to something like this:

```
switcher[config["aSection"]["anotherid"])] = func
```

Then you need to define func to look something like this:

```
#CONF
#[aSection]
#pluginid='anotherid'
#functionHead: anotherfunction2

#PYTHON
#config is an instance of a config parser
def func (param):
  exec ("%s(param)" % config["aSection"]["functionHead"])
```

This will call a function called `anotherfunction2` that you have previously defined. Call the func like this:

```
switcher[config["aSection"]["anotherid"])](param)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have to be honest, that i didn't fully understand your solution, but it gave me a hint how  i can solve my problem. Instead of using exec like you did, i used eval.